# Using numba to compile dynamic functions

Tags: python, numba

I'm writing a program which dynamically detects and imports python functions and detects which input parameters and outputs that is will expect/generate.

Like so:

```
def importFunctions(self, filename):

    moduleImport = __import__(filename)
    members = getmembers(moduleImport, isfunction)
    functions = []
    for m in members:
        function = getattr(moduleImport, m[0])
        number_of_inputs = function.__code__.co_argcount
        inputs = function.__code__.co_varnames
        if number_of_inputs > 1:
            inputs = inputs[0:number_of_inputs-1]
        elif number_of_inputs == 1:
            inputOne = inputs[0]
            inputs = []
            inputs.append(inputOne)
        outputs = function.__annotations__["return"]

        functions.append([function, inputs, outputs])
    return functions
```

This works only when I properly annotate the function, an example function could look something like this:

```
    from numba import jit
    @jit
    def subtraction(a, b) -> ["difference"]:
        a = float(a)
        b = float(b)
        difference = a - b
        return (difference,)
```

This work perfectly fine without the decorator, but when I want to add the numba "jit" decorator to a function, I get an error saying that the imported function is missing the "return"-annotation.

### UPDATE

Having tried to aces the original function by using "func.py_func" as suggested by @Rutger Kassies, my suspicions are that either getmembers or getattr it not proporely importing the numba to-be-compiled function.

It seems that getmembers finds "jit" as a separate member, and doesn't correctly associate it with the original function. The way it's written above, the 'function' named "jit", is of type function, as it should be. However, calling it returns a "<function _jit..wrapper". This has me scratching my head quite a bit but I suppose the 'getattr' is somehow behind this.

My guess is that I will have to fin another approach to dynamically importing functions that doesn't rely on "getattr".

Comment: Please provide a complete example that use Numba (if possible something we can copy-past to reproduce).

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with the `numba.jit` or `numba.njit` decorators, you can access the original function, in all it's annotated glory, by accessing the `.py_func` attribute. A simple example:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
from typing import get_type_hints, Annotated, Any

custom_output_type = Annotated[Any, "something"]

@numba.njit
def func(x: float) -> custom_output_type:
    return x**2

# trigger compilation, not required
func(1.2)

get_type_hints(func.py_func, include_extras=True)
```

Which returns what you would expect from a regular Python function:
`{'x': float, 'return': typing.Annotated[typing.Any, 'something']}`

It would be similar when using the `inspect` module.

It gets more complicated when you use the other decorators lie `vectorize` & `guvectorize`, unfortunately. See for example:
https://numba.discourse.group/t/using-annotations-with-numba-gu-vectorize-functions/1008

It's probably best to rely as much as possible on the inspect & typing modules over accessing the private attributes of a function.

Comment: So in my specific case, where I import functions from a different file, adding the jit-decorator replaces the original function with a function called 'jit', and It doesn't have the attribute 'py_func'. I'm placing the code for the importer in my original post.

Comment: I think it could have to do with how I use the getmembers?

Comment: Okay so I believe that using getattr() in conjunction with getmembers() may not be the way to go. It seems that getmembers find "jit" as a separate member, and doesn't seem to correctly associate it with the original function. The way it's written in my OP, the 'function' is of type function, as it should be. However, calling it returns a "<function _jit.<locals>.wrapper". This has me scratching my head quite a bit but I suppose the 'getattr' is somehow behind this.